# How to add repeated values to string collection?

Tags: .net, vb.net, collections

I'm currently working on a project I've been making for a few months now. It is close to having version 2 released, which will include bookmarks. To store these bookmarks, I have used the Settings menu in the project's Properties. I created two `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection`'s, one called "BookmarkNames" and the other called "BookmarkAddresses." I have a menu in a dropdown from the menu bar in my app that has the bookmark buttons. These are added on startup by iterating through the collections with a for-next loop. To test it, I made it add 2 items to each. Before it does the button-adding, I add "Bing" and "Google" to `My.Settings.BookmarkNames` and their respective addresses to `My.Settings.BookmarkAddresses`. I noticed that when it finishes launching, it only added one button, called "Bing." Clicking the button did go to the Bing site, so it must have done something right. However, it has skipped Google. To see what has happened, I added a simple `Console.PrintLine()` to the end of the for-next loop. This prints the item that it is currently on in the BookmarkNames collection, and thus it should print two lines: "Google" and "Bing." However, it prints random numbers of each, sometimes it'll say "Google" 5 times then alternate between "Google" and "Bing."

My question is simple: What is the reason for the extra repeated values? Why are they being added and printed? I can figure out the whole "one button being created" problem myself, as long as I can figure out what is going on there.

**The code in question is:**

```
'WRE: This loads the bookmarks into the bookmarks menu.
My.Settings.BookmarksNames.Add("Google")
My.Settings.BookmarksAddresses.Add("http://www.google.com/")
My.Settings.BookmarksNames.Add("Bing")
My.Settings.BookmarksAddresses.Add("http://www.bing.com/")
If My.Settings.BookmarksAddresses.Count > 0 Then
    For counter As Integer = 0 To My.Settings.BookmarksAddresses.Count - 1
        bmb.Text = My.Settings.BookmarksNames.Item(counter)
        bmb.bookmarkURL = My.Settings.BookmarksAddresses.Item(counter)
        but_Bmarks.DropDownItems.Add(bmb)
        Console.WriteLine(My.Settings.BookmarksNames.Item(counter))
    Next
Else
    ...
End If
```

Comment: Add your code here. It is small and there is no reason to put it on an external site

Comment: The If-statement if superfluous as the For-loop will automatically not loop if the Count is 0.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes It's only there because I am going to add an Else-statement that will add a string to the menu that says that it's empty.

Comment: Okay I added an Else-part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop you have a variable named bmb that seems to be some kind of object.

This variabile is initialized somewhere not visibile in your code. But inside the loop is reused the same instance. So you at first loop you add correctly the values for Google, but at the next loop yuo use again the same variable and change its content to Bing. In this way you change also the content already added

Inside the loop you need to reinitialize the variable

```
   For counter As Integer = 0 To My.Settings.BookmarksAddresses.Count - 1
       bmb = new SomeKindOfClassHere();
       bmb.Text = My.Settings.BookmarksNames.Item(counter)
       bmb.bookmarkURL = My.Settings.BookmarksAddresses.Item(counter)
       but_Bmarks.DropDownItems.Add(bmb)
       ....
```

Comment: Ahhh thanks. That helps with the single button showing up. However, it doesn't help with the multiple of each value...

Comment: @WillEccles:  The settings are stored permanently. When you re-run your application the old values are still there and you are adding them one more time!

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes the Run button does not use saved settings. It reverts to default, which in this case is an empty collection. Also, It is repeating each thing by itself sometimes, such as saying "Google" many times, whereas if it were re-adding them it would be alternating between them.

Comment: Add a `Console.WriteLine(My.Settings.BookmarksNames.Count)` before `My.Settings.BookmarksNames.Add("Google")`.